# Unity3D syncing audio with object position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple board game where tokens get moved from square to square. I am using a coroutine to move the tokens. It does something like below

```
IEnumerator MoveTokenCoRoutine(int steps)
{

    while (steps > 0)
    {
       transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        yield return null;
        --steps;
    }

}
```

The clip is a sliding sound for 2 seconds.

Steps, is how many squares a token should move using Lerp. The only time I could get it synced is with below parameters.

1) Set the lerp speed to 10 which is default speed i use to move
2) Step = 1 (move one square)
3) Call Play() just before while

With this scenario movement and sound effect stay pretty much in sync.

However, if steps get more than 1 and I put the Play() inside loop it just plays one time and stops. But the token keeps moving until while ends.

What approaches do I have to keep this in sync?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much salvagable from your code, unfortunately.

A better working variant would look like this:

```
IEnumerator MoveTokenCoRoutine()
{
    float currentTime=0.0f;  // note: NOT in seconds, 1.0f = end of sound sample
    Vector3 oldPosition = transform.position;
    float startTime = Time.time;
    while (currentTime < 1.0f) {
       currentTime = (Time.time - startTime)/ DurationInSeconds ;
       transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(oldPosition, newPos,  currentTime );
       yield return null;
    }
}
```

Required variables:

- `Vector3 newPos` Target position at animation end
- `float DurationInSeconds` Length of the sound sample in seconds